# Pass custom labels as an array to Chart JS Tool tip

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to display some information using Chart.js in the horizontalBar configuration.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("eventVisitors"), {
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: {
    labels: ["monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Friday"],
    datasets: [
      {
        maxBarThickness: 1,
        label: "Visitors",
        backgroundColor: [
          "#D1E6E9",
          "#566573",
          "#201736",
          "#707B7C",
          "#4A235A"
        ],
        data: [5, 4, 6, 7]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: { display: false },
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: "Visitor Origin"
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: true,
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 16,

            beginAtZero: true,
            callback: function(value) {
              if (value % 1 === 0) {
                return value;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: true,
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 16
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

The above works great and plots the graph as it should. The tooltip when hovered on each bar shows:

**Monday**
**Visitors:5**

However, what I need is to be able to get the tooltip to look in another array which will have some strings that correspond to each data point for it to display; so, for example

```js
["Example Text display for Monday", "Tuesday Title", "Wednesday title"]
```

Such that when hovered, the tooltip will show

**Example Text display for Monday**
**Monday**
**Visitors:5**

I have done some readings with respect to callbacks in Chart.js but unfortunately my JavaScript/jQuery is only at an intermediate level. Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an **array**, I would suggest you to use an **object** instead (similar to a map behavior), in that way I think it will make more sense.

```js
const days = {
  Monday: "Example description for monday",
  Tuesday: "Example description for tueday",
  Wednesday: "Example description for wednesday",
  Thursday: "Example description for thursday",
  Friday: "Example description for friday",
  Saturday: "Example description for saturday",
  Sunday: "Example description for sunday"
};
```

In your `labels` key in your chart `options`, you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all keys as the label. And the key value is the description of your tooltip.

```js
data: {
  labels: Object.keys(days),
  datasets: [
    {
      maxBarThickness: 1,
      label: "Visitors",
      backgroundColor: [
        "#D1E6E9",
        "#566573",
        "#201736",
        "#707B7C",
        "#4A235A"
      ],
      data: [5, 4, 6, 7]
    },
  ],
},
...
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    beforeTitle: tooltip => days[tooltip[0].yLabel],
  },
},
```

Everything together

```js
const days = {
  Monday: "Example description for monday",
  Tuesday: "Example description for tueday",
  Wednesday: "Example description for wednesday",
  Thursday: "Example description for thursday",
  Friday: "Example description for friday",
  Saturday: "Example description for saturday",
  Sunday: "Example description for sunday"
};

new Chart(document.getElementById("eventVisitors"), {
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: {
    labels: Object.keys(days),
    datasets: [
      {
        maxBarThickness: 1,
        label: "Visitors",
        backgroundColor: [
          "#D1E6E9",
          "#566573",
          "#201736",
          "#707B7C",
          "#4A235A"
        ],
        data: [5, 4, 6, 7],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    legend: { display: false },
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: "Visitor Origin"
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        beforeTitle: tooltip => days[tooltip[0].yLabel],
      },
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: true,
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 16,
            beginAtZero: true,
            callback: function(value) {
              if (value % 1 === 0) {
                return value;
              }
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: true,
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 16
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.  I have done this, but the tooltip doesn't seem to be returning the string...

Comment: I tested and it worked for me. It's probably something wrong at your side. Care to show your current codes.

Comment: I have it on code pen here if you would like to have a look:

https://codepen.io/tyson-adeyemi/pen/zYYyEmx

Comment: @oluwatyson Updated answer, the issue was because the tooltip key `label` should be `yLabel` instead. The tooltip key was `label` for my case but it appears to be `yLabel` for your case.